# Indesign CS5 relink all links when moving to a different computer

Tags: adobe-indesign, images, cs5

I have done a lot of work on a lot of files.  To give them to a new designer working for us, I have put them on an external HDD and passed them over.  But he now has to open up every file individually and relink them to the External HDD or his own HDD.  This is really time consuming (there are hundreds of documents).  Is there a quicker way to do this?  We really only need to be able to tell InDesign that the front of the image location has changed, as all of the other parts of the file structure are the same.

This would save me loads of time, and I'm sure there must be a solution...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found another answer.  In the Links Panel there's a drop down menu in the top right, choose Relink to Folder and it should relink all the files in one step.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for because even when you package it does not automatically relink to the new Links folder (unless there is a setting I am missing when packaging). Thanks @Eoin!

Comment: @ispaany no worries glad it helped someone.  Not sure about that packaging issue but it would be a useful feature.

Answer (score 1):

`File` > `Package` should also work wonders: this saves the *.indd file and all linked files, fonts etc. in a single directory you can then pass around at leisure. Watch out for license troubles, though!

Comment: Thanks, I have now discovered this feature. License problems didn't occur here, the client provides all of the material and is the licensee. Cheers though :)

Comment: This feature is great, but is there a way to do this for multiple documents?  I'm working on a 56 page magazine, and we save each spread as a separate document, I don't really need the font file multiple times for example.

Comment: You could try to collate the separate documents into a 'book', using `File > New > Book` and then package that. I'm not sure whether it'll work though. It does work wonders for your page numbering!

Answer (score 0):

Chose File, then Package. All the links and fonts are then copied into a new fully-contained folder with a copy of the actual .INDD file.

If you're looking at a magazine, you'd probably either want to join the separate files as a book or simply merge the files into one document.

Also, if the links are all in the same place, once you relink one image, the others should automatically relink. In that case, you wouldn't have to package the files. But most designers find it easiest to package the files.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

**AppleScript to relink missing images in Indesign.**

If the images are stored all together in another directory, it's a simple matter to relink one of the links to that directory and select the checkbox for Indesign to look for other images in the same directory.

But what about the situation when you need to relink images back to a directory that contains multiple subdirectories where the links are filed – like in the case of an image library?

I wrote this AppleScript to solve the problem.
http://www.drscripto.com/?p=8

All you have to do is point the script to the top level of a directory and it will search every subdirectory for the missing files. After this has been done once, an index file is created in the top level and this makes subsequent relinking faster.