# InDesign relink Index Markers

Tags: adobe-indesign, html, mac, cc-2017

Working with Indesign Creative Cloud 2017, I've run into an issue.  I was delivered files and the supplied IDML file has about 150 Index entries that I need to relink in the content.  When I export the content to HTML, I see what appears as `_idIndexMarker` and on a particular page set where it appears the index was linked still shows the linking portion from Story Editor:

[image]

export results in HTML:

```
<a id="_idIndexMarker031"></a>foobar
```

Looking at how an index works I ran across [Create an index](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/creating-index.html) but I wasn't able to find anything on the re-linking process.

Researching for a relink solution I came across "[Work with markers](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/markers.html)" which discusses how to show them, I already know that and there is no information on the re-linking process.

I looked into examining if there were any other panels, which led to the `Cross-references Panel` but the documentation I found, [Cross-references](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/cross-references.html) doesn't help.

If I search for InDesign re-link index I ran across [Indesign CS5 relink all links when moving to a different computer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/19328/indesign-cs5-relink-all-links-when-moving-to-a-different-computer) so I tried `File -> Package` but I received the same results.

When I search the tag [[tag:indesign] index](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Badobe-indesign%5D%20index) I don't see any questions asked regarding re-linking.

When I look into a possible [scripting solution](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6js/pc_Index.html) it appears it's mostly read-only but that is for CS6 and I'm using CC17 as there is no mention of any index changes in [What’s New with InDesign CC 2017](https://indesignsecrets.com/whats-new-with-indesign-cc-2017.php)

How can I re-link an Indesign document's index entries without having to re-create them?  Is there a way I can isolate this in the backend so I could make a script out of it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the alt-click option on the link command within the Links panel. This lets you choose a directory which it will scan to fix any missing links. If you have your assets in multiple folders then you just need to repeat until all are fixed.

I tested this with CS6, I can test with CC17 tonight.

The steps to follow are:

1. Show the lists panel (*Window* -> *Links*)
2. Select any asset
3. Alt-Click on the re-link icon at the bottom of the panel

[image]

4. Select the directory, it will auto highlight the first asset that matches
5. Confirm the first asset

After step 5, it will auto update all links and tell you how many were fixed.

I'm not sure how to do this in a script, however this should resolve your problem if you do not have too many different folders.

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with the question at all. The Links panel shows links to embedded files; index markers are links to locations in (usually) the same document. They are completely unrelated.

Comment: I thought it was about file links as the question talked about re-linking, the reference to moving to a new computer and the comments about the file paths and putting it all back together and updating the links. After rereading the question and the comments I'm still not sure if it's internal index or linked files.